# The relation $(1+\lambda \Delta )^{-1}y_n=(a-1)a^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a^ky_k+Aa^{-n}$.

Tags: finite-differences

I want to prove the above relation for $\lambda=a/(a-1)$ where $a\ne 1$, and $A$ is an arbitrary constant, without induction on $n$.

And $\Delta z_n = z_{n+1}-z_n$ for some sequence $z_n$.

So I tried to geometrically expand this term and I get:

$$(1+\lambda \Delta)^{-1}y_n = (1-\lambda \Delta+\lambda^2\Delta^2-\ldots)y_n$$

I don't see how to get this sum in the RHS, I know that $\Delta^{-1}y_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_k+B$ where $B$ is some arbitrary constant.

I don't see how to relate this to the above relation.

Any hints? it should be straightforward, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to invoke $ \left( 1 + \lambda \Delta \right) $ on the RHS.

Denote $ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{a^k y_k} $

then $ \mathrm{RHS} = (a-1)a^{-n}\cdot S_{n-1} + A \cdot a^{-n} $

Note that  $  \Delta \left( a^{-n} \cdot S_{n-1} \right) = 
a^{-\left(n+1\right)} \cdot S_n - a^{-n}\cdot S_{n-1} $ and therefore

$$
\begin{split}
(1 + \lambda \cdot \Delta )\left( a^{-n} \cdot S_{n-1} \right) = 
a^{-n} \cdot S_{n-1} + \frac{a}{a-1}\left(a^{-\left(n+1\right)} \cdot S_n - a^{-n}\cdot S_{n-1}\right)  = \\
a^{-n} S_{n-1} \cdot \left(1- \frac{a}{a-1}\right) + a^{-n}\cdot S_n \cdot \frac{1}{a-1} = \\
 a^{-n} \cdot \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{a-1} = 
a^{-n} \cdot \frac{{a^n \cdot y_n }}{a-1} = \frac{y_n}{a-1}
\end{split}
$$

Therefore we have $ \left( 1 + \lambda \Delta \right) \left( \left( a -1\right)  a^{-n} \cdot S_{n - 1} \right) = y_n $

Denote $ z_n = \left( 1 + \lambda \Delta \right)^{-1} y_n $. Then $ z_n = \left( a -1\right)  a^{-n} \cdot S_{n - 1} + w_n $ where $ w_n $ belongs to the kernel of $ 1 + \lambda \Delta $, i.e.

$$
\begin{split}
w_n + \lambda \cdot \left( w_{n+1} - w_n \right) = 0 \\
\iff \\
w_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot w_n + w_n = \left( \frac{1-a}{a} + 1 \right) \cdot w_n  \\ 
\iff \\
w_{n+1} = a^{-1} w_{n}
\end{split}
$$

which means that $ w_{n} = A \cdot a^{-n} $ where $ A $ is a constant.

Comment: Nice solution, should've seen it.

Comment: BTW, you proved this identity by operating $(1+\lambda\Delta)$ on the RHS, but I didn't know this identity beforehand (I mean before I looked at this exercise), how would I find what is $(1+\lambda\Delta)^{-1}y_n$? I mean beside expanding by geometric sum, the other approach I thought of is denoting by $(1+\lambda\Delta)z_n=y_n$, and then to try to find what is $z_n$ w.r.t. $y_n$ explicitly, but I didn't get far with this approach.